# What is security access for child record when master is private

Tags: security, relationships, junction-object, owd

There is one junction object in which one master object has owd public access and one master object has private access

Answer (score 4):

The *first* master-detail relationship you create on your junction object becomes the primary relationship. This affects the following for the junction object records:

- Look and feel: The junction object's detail and edit pages use the color and any associated icon of the primary master object.
- Record ownership: The junction object records inherit the value of the Owner field from their associated primary master record. Because objects on the detail side of a relationship do not have a visible Owner field, this is only relevant if you later delete both master-detail relationships on your junction object.

The **second** master-detail relationship you create on your junction object becomes the secondary relationship. If you delete the primary master-detail relationship or convert it to a lookup relationship, the secondary master object becomes primary.

For reference check this [article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000212396&language=en_US&type=1).

Answer (score 0):

The Junction object get the Private access , in order to get the read access on junction object ,both masters should have at least read access